# why the regular value of a smooth map is everywhere dense?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $ f:M\to N$ be a smooth mapping between two smooth manifold(dim M>dimN).
A.B.Brown's theorem told me :the set of regular values is everywhere dense in N.
so ,what about $f:U \to R^n$ where U is an open subset of $R^n$[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEFZE.png)

(I have known Sard theorem which describes the critical set is measure zero.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that each $q \in N \setminus f(M)$ is a regular value because then $f^{-1}(q) = \emptyset$ and thus trivially each $p \in f^{-1}(q)$ is a regular point.